# jmeter converting a human readable date to Epoch

Tags: datetime, jmeter

I have a script that needs two timestamps, one for 'today' at 02:30 and one for 'tomorrow' at 02:30. To generate the dates was fairly easy, using;

```
date1=${__time("yyyy.MM.dd 02:30:00")}
date2=${__timeShift("yy.MM.dd 02:30:00",,P1D,,)}
```

But the POST request needs the dates in Epoch format. How can I convert the output of the above into Epochs?

An option that I found was to use;

```
date1a=date1.getTime().toString()
```

But that didn't work (no signature of method). Related to that I did find a jmeter 5.3 bug where the dateutil.jar is missing, but adding it made no difference.

There are lots of options for converting Epoch to human readable, but they aren't reversible processes.

Alternatively, is there a way of calculating the Epoch directly, again for 'today' at 2:30 and 'tomorrow' at 2:30?

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't inline JMeter Functions or Variables into scripts, as per [JSR223 Sampler documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

   - `The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance.`
   - `When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement. Instead use script parameters`
2. I believe you can achieve your goal using good old [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), example code to parse your string and add 24 hours to it:

   ```
   def today = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss').parse('2020.11.06 02:30:00')
   log.info('Today:    ' + today)
   def tomorrow = new Date(today.getTime() + 86400000L)
   log.info('Tomorrow: ' + tomorrow)

   log.info('Today epoch   : ' + today.getTime())
   log.info('Tomorrow epoch: ' + tomorrow.getTime())
   ```

Demo:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: That makes sense, but the getTime() doesn't work for me (the no signature of method error). Although I'm guessing by your code it's because my dates are Strings but you're using a Date?